# Чтение текстового файла из zip (Ruby)

Tags: linux, ruby, zip

Прочитать content.xml из архива можно так

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'zip'

ContentXML = 'content.xml'
odtfile = ARGF.argv[0]
puts "Read file: " + odtfile
puts Zip::File.open(odtfile).read(ContentXML)
```

Все просто и лаконично. Ну а если мне нужно прочитать его по строчкам?
И можно ли его, не экстрагируя, передать парсеру XML?

Comment: если тег linux - **zcat filname**

Comment: Как правило парсеры XML в языках типа Ruby или Python связаны с библиотеками компрессии. (Насчёт Python я уверен, так как идеология программирования на нём подразумевает передачу объекта типа *file*, а всякие компрессоры умеют конструировать объекты такого типа)